# Selectedindex in listview, throwing up an error!

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys, the following code shows what i am trying to do.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iDeliverySelected = lstDeliveryDetails.SelectedIndex;
        bool addEdit = false;
    }
```

The selectedindex is throwing up the following error..
'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas why? First time I have tried to use SelectedIndex, not sure if i am using it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class does not have a `SelectedIndex` property. It has a [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

```
ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indexes = this.ListView1.SelectedIndices;

double price = 0.0;
foreach ( int index in indexes )
{
  price += Double.Parse(this.ListView1.Items[index].SubItems[1].Text);
}
```

Comment: What type is this?
It says I cannot convert to int?

Comment: @Luke - `SelectedIndices` returns a `SelectedIndexCollection`. You can iterate of this collection to get each selected item (as there can be more than 1), using a `foreach` loop. Take a look at the linked pages.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView does have a SelectedIndex method so a general internet search comes up with what looks like (if you're not paying close attention) an extension property to Forms.ListView.  In the case I've got right now my Forms.ListView has MultiSelect=false so I know there can only be one selection. So it seems the quickest way to get the current selection would be ListView1.SelectedIndicies[0]?

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one selection so look at:

```
ListView.SelectedIndices
```